# Passing arguments by the hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, c#, command-line-arguments

I have some interesting question. Is it possible somehow to pass some parameters to C# application by means of hyperlink? If it possible, how to get them in application code?

I tried to use hyperlinks like this "C:\Users\User\Documents\MyApp.exe#Test param!1234" where "MyApp.exe" is my application and "Test param!1234" arguments to transmit. I tried get this arguments in application like command line arguments, but there is no some like "Test param!1234"

Please, help me

Comment: Have you tried using %20 instead of # to separate the file from the command line argument?

Comment: Yeah, I tried. But when I try to save link, the %20 is replaced by a space and the link is not working.